# Bash verbose command with evaluating parameters

Tags: bash, logging, verbose

I am trying to log the command with its parameters (after evaluating if necessary) in Bash.

I am trying to use `set -v`:

```
$ variable=2
$ set -v
$ sleep $variable
sleep $variable
```

As you can see, it prints `sleep $variable`. I want to log `sleep 2` instead.

My original command is more complex, so I don't want to `echo` each parameter one by one. (And it is probably more error prone to do so).

Comment: Are you looking for `set -x`?

Comment: Omg, yes, thanks. :-)

Comment: If it wasn't so late at night here, I'd write a proper answer... :-/

Comment: Just write the same things as an answer. And goodnight. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -v` (or `set -o verbose`) will output every command as it is read, without expanding things.

`set -x` (or `set -o xtrace`) will output the expanded command line before execution.  Each line is prepended by the `PS4` prompt (usually a `+`) and for commands executed as part of command substitutions, the prompt will be "doubled up" (`++`).

The trace will be written to the file descriptor indicated by `$BASH_XTRACEFD` (or to the shell's standard error by default).

Comment: I guess `help set` should have been my friend.